# Combining TypoScript and Fluid: Iterations?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-7.x, typo3-7.6.x

I'm combining a TypoScript CONTENT Object with a fluid template.

In the page template:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.myItem" />
```

In TS:

```
lib.myItem = CONTENT
lib.myItem {
  table = tt_content
  select.where = colPos = 0
  select.languageField = sys_language_uid
  renderObj = FLUIDTEMPLATE
  renderObj {
    file = {$customContentTemplatePath}/Myfile.html
    layoutRootPath = {$customContentLayoutPath}
    partialRootPath = {$customContentPartialPath}
    dataProcessing {
      10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
      10.references.fieldName = image
    }
  }
}
```

In Myfile.html:

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}

<div class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns">
    <f:for each="{files}" as="file">
      <v:media.image src="{file}" srcset="1200,900,600" srcsetDefault="600" alt="{file.alternative}" treatIdAsReference="1"/>
    </f:for>
    <div class="fp-ql-txt">
      {data.header} >
    </div>
</div>
```

But now I realized that because the template is applied by the renderObj for each content element, I don't have access to fluid's for-each information about iteration. So, I can't do this:

```
  <f:for each="{data}" as="item" iteration="itemIterator">
  {itemIterator.cycle}
  </f:for>
```

to find out in which of the rendered items we are ... because each element is rendered individually by `renderObj`.

How can I get the iteration information about the renderObj's products? Only in TS with the old and terrifying counters as in http://typo3-beispiel.net/index.php?id=9 ?

Answer (score 2):

You could make your own IteratorDataProcessor:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\MyExt\DataProcessing;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\SingletonInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer;
use TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\DataProcessorInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\Exception\ContentRenderingException;

/**
 * This data processor will keep track of how often he was called and whether it is an
 * even or odd number.
 */
class IteratorProcessor implements DataProcessorInterface, SingletonInterface
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $count = 0;

    /**
     * Process data for multiple CEs and keep track of index
     *
     * @param ContentObjectRenderer $cObj The content object renderer, which contains data of the content element
     * @param array $contentObjectConfiguration The configuration of Content Object
     * @param array $processorConfiguration The configuration of this processor
     * @param array $processedData Key/value store of processed data (e.g. to be passed to a Fluid View)
     * @return array the processed data as key/value store
     * @throws ContentRenderingException
     */
    public function process(ContentObjectRenderer $cObj, array $contentObjectConfiguration, array $processorConfiguration, array $processedData)
    {
        $iterator = [];
        $iterator['index'] = $this->count;
        $iterator['isFirst'] = $this->count === 0;
        $this->count++;
        $iterator['cycle'] = $this->count;
        $iterator['isEven'] = $this->count % 2 === 0;
        $iterator['isOdd'] = !$iterator['isEven'];
        $processedData['iterator'] = $iterator;
        return $processedData;
    }
}
```

In Typoscript you pass your data through that processor:

```
dataProcessing {
    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
    10 {
        references.fieldName = image
    }
    20 = Vendor\MyExt\DataProcessing\IteratorProcessor
}
```

In fluid you can access the stuff you set in your DataProcessor with e.g. `{iterator.isFirst}`.

Comment: I guess you didn't just write that ad hoc – do you have that use case too? Do you think it's a valid scenario?

Comment: Of course it is. I'll use that very DataProcessor in a project of mine.

Comment: ehem... I put it into `EXT:template/Classes/DataProcessing/IteratorProcessor.php`, namespaced it to `STUBR\Template\DataProcessing` and called it with `renderObj.dataProcessing.20 = STUBR\Template\DataProcessing\IteratorProcessor` – which gives me the Exception `Processor class name "STUBR\Template\DataProcessing\IteratorProcessor" does not exist`. Do I have to register the DataProcessor somewhere?

Comment: No registration required. You just have tomake sure your class is loaded. :) Bennis answers is very legit as well. As long as you do not need to add special stuff to your iterator that fluids own iteration is not capable of, I'd go with his approach.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the DatabaseQueryProcessor shipped with the TYPO3 Core.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html#dataprocessing

Please note that data processing only work inside the FLUIDTEMPLATE cObject.

You also find a working example inside the documentation.

Comment: With the DatabaseQueryProcessor instead of renderObj, the iteration would be already available, right?